# Adding Property To System.ApplicationException WithOut Using Inheritance

Tags: c#, wcf

In my wcf methods am catching methods at the top teir only. So if any exceptions are thrown im my methods below the top tier they will be automatically causght as an ApplicationException.

I want to add a property or find a way to hold the inputData of the method that crashed, so when the ApplicationException is causght is has the methods inputData attached to it.

Is this scenerio possible?

I am using IErrorHandler to catch the exceptions. How do I extract the inputData from the method that crashed out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you turn trace on, you can get this data. Otherwise you need to catch the exception in each WCF method and save any data into a custom exception you would then use in an [IErrorHandler](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2008/10/16/wcf-ierrorhandler-and-propagating-faults.aspx)

Comment: I am using IErrorHandler to catch the exceptions. How do I extract the inputData from the method that crashed out of it?

Comment: In that case, you first need a try/catch inside your method, inside the catch create a custom exception with the inputData you want need to see. There is no way in WCF to have this done for you. We have tried AOP solutions but they had undesired side effects

Comment: There is no way to get that information in IErrorHandler HandleError method?

Comment: Not directly. Custom exceptions containing that are the only way I know of to pass that data into the IErrorHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Try/Catch loop to catch exceptions in a particular code block. Otherwise you can use the StackTrace to look at where the exception occured when catching at the top level.

Comment: How do I get the input data of the method that crashed out of the stackTrace?